# How can I edit the pages of this small animation on scroll book?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this cool small book which changes content while scrolling. The animation is good. I can't find any image link for the pages of the book. I want to have my own text and images on it. How can I edit it? Is it possible to add a text or an image on the book's cover? What is the url/source for the pages used in this small book?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/jh3y/pen/VweZryJ)

HTML

```
 - const SRC = ['Book', 'Cubes', 'Elon', 'Gun', 'Kitkat', 'Launch', 'Pino', 'Pokedex', 'Record', 'Tcannon']
mixin sketch()
  - const src = SRC[Math.floor(Math.random() * (SRC.length + 1))]
  img(src=`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/${src || 'Book'}-sketch.svg`)

- const PAGES = 10
.book
  .book__spine
  .page.book__page.book__cover.book__cover--front(style='--page-index: 1;')
    .page__half.page__half--front
      span.code.
        set(FOLD,{transformOrigin:"50% 100%",scaleY:0}),set(CLIPS,{transformOrigin:"50% 0"}),set(".cannon__shirt",{opacity:0}),set(".cannon",{y:28}),set(".text--ordered .char",{y:"100%"});const SPEED=.15,FOLD_TL=()=>new timeline().to(LEFT_ARM,{duration:SPEED,rotateY:-180,transformOrigin:`${100*(22/65.3)}% 50%`},0).to(RIGHT_ARM,{duration:SPEED,rotateY:-180,transformOrigin:`${100*((65.3-22)/65.3)}% 50%`},SPEED).to(FOLD,{duration:SPEED/4,scaleY:1},2*SPEED).to(FOLD,{duration:SPEED,y:-47},2*SPEED+.01).to(CLIPS,{duration:SPEED,scaleY:.2},2*SPEED).to(".cannon",{duration:SPEED,y:0},2*SPEED),LOAD_TL=()=>new timeline().to(".button__shirt",{transformOrigin:"50% 13%",rotate:90,duration:.15}).to(".button__shirt",{duration:.15,y:60}).to(".t-shirt__cannon",{y:5,repeat:1,yoyo:!0,duration:.1}).to(".t-shirt__cannon",{y:50,duration:.5,delay:.1}),FIRE_TL=()=>new timeline().set(".t-shirt__cannon",{rotate:48,x:-85,scale:2.5}).set(".cannon__shirt",{opacity:1}).to(".t-shirt__cannon-content",{duration:1,y:-35}).to(".t-shirt__cannon-content",{duration:.25,y:-37.5}).to(".t-shirt__cannon-content",{duration:.015,y:-30.5}).to(".cannon__shirt",{onStart:()=>CLIP.play(),duration:.5,y:"-25vmax"},"<").to(".text--ordered .char",{duration:.15,stagger:.1,y:"0%"}).to("button",{duration:.15*7,"--hue":116,"--lightness":55},"<"),ORDER_TL=new timeline({paused:!0});ORDER_TL.set(".cannon__shirt",{opacity:0}),ORDER_TL.set("button",{"--hue":260,"--lightness":20}),ORDER_TL.to("button",{scale:300/BUTTON.offsetWidth,duration:SPEED}),ORDER_TL.to(".text--order .char",{stagger:.1,y:"100%",duration:.1}),ORDER_TL.to(SHIRT,{x:BUTTON.offsetWidth/2-33,duration:.2}),ORDER_TL.add(FOLD_TL()),ORDER_TL.add(LOAD_TL()),ORDER_TL.add(FIRE_TL()),BUTTON.addEventListener("click",()=>{1===ORDER_TL.progress()?(document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--hue",360*Math.random()),ORDER_TL.time(0),ORDER_TL.pause()):0===ORDER_TL.progress()&&ORDER_TL.play()});
      svg.sticker(xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 316 306')
        path(d='M155 0c-37 0-63 8-85 30-6-6-21-7-29-7C22 23 6 38 6 56c1 24 9 34 24 40l-9 2-21 4 3 22c3 0 8 1 9 4 6 7 2 14 3 26 2 21 7 33 14 40 14 67 62 112 127 112 70 0 118-45 132-112 6-7 11-20 13-40 1-12-3-19 3-26 2-3 6-4 9-4l3-22-21-4-10-2c17-7 24-26 24-40 0-18-15-33-34-33-9 0-23 1-30 7-23-22-51-30-90-30z' fill='hsl(0, 0%, 96%)')
        g(transform='matrix(1.34105 0 0 1.34105 -43 -1047)')
          path(d='M243 894c0 61-36 106-94 106-55 0-92-45-92-106s38-86 91-86 95 25 95 86z' fill='#803300')
          path(d='M212 958c0 20-29 39-63 39-35 0-61-19-61-39s26-33 61-33 63 13 63 33z' fill='#e9c6af')
          path(d='M181 932c0 7-19 24-30 24s-32-17-32-24c0-8 20-13 31-13 12 0 31 5 31 13z')
          ellipse(cx='68.3' cy='827.7' rx='23.8' ry='23.1' fill='#803300')
          path(d='M85 826a17 16 0 00-17-14 17 16 0 00-16 16 17 16 0 0016 16 17 16 0 001 0l3-4a66 66 0 0111-12l2-2z' fill='#e9c6af')
          ellipse(ry='23.1' rx='23.8' cy='827.7' cx='-231.2' transform='scale(-1 1)' fill='#803300')
          path(d='M215 826a17 16 0 0116-14 17 16 0 0117 16 17 16 0 01-17 16 17 16 0 01-1 0l-2-4a66 66 0 00-11-12l-2-2z' fill='#e9c6af')
          path(d='M148 815c-14 0-26 1-38 4v11a199 199 0 0180 1v-11c-13-3-27-5-42-5z' fill='red')
          path(d='M165 816a16 8 0 015 5 16 8 0 01-6 6l26 4v-11l-25-4z' fill='#e50000')
          path(d='M148 789c-43 0-76 20-83 64 12-11 28-19 45-23 0 0-2-12 10-16 15-4 19-4 28-4 10 0 15 0 30 4s12 17 12 17c18 5 32 11 45 22-8-46-43-64-87-64z' fill='#1a1a1a')
          circle(cx='97.2' cy='894.1' r='11.2' fill='#faa' fill-opacity='.6')
          circle(cy='894.1' cx='201.9' r='11.2' fill='#faa' fill-opacity='.6')
          path(d='M97 864a21 21 0 01-7 16 21 21 0 01-16 5M204 864a21 21 0 006 16 21 21 0 0016 5' fill='none' stroke='#e9afaf' stroke-width='3' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round')
          g
            path(d='M77 855c-6 0-13 0-23 2l-14 3 2 15 7 2c3 5 1 10 2 18 3 28 12 34 26 35 8 1 23 3 33-1s19-10 25-18c6-9 6-18 10-26 3-5 8-4 10 0 3 8 4 17 10 26 6 8 15 14 24 18 11 4 26 2 34 1 14-1 23-7 26-35 1-8-2-13 2-18l7-2 2-15-15-3c-15-3-23-2-34-2h-13l-25 4c-8 2-15 7-23 6-8 0-15-5-23-6l-25-4H77z')
            path(d='M85 860c-10 1-25 1-28 13-3 15-3 32 6 45 7 11 23 9 35 9 19-1 35-16 40-34 2-8 4-14 1-19-6-10-20-12-31-13l-23-1z' fill='#333')
            path(d='M56 864a4 2 0 01-4 2 4 2 0 01-4-2 4 2 0 014-1 4 2 0 014 1' fill='#b3b3b3')
            path(d='M215 860c10 1 24 1 28 13 3 15 3 32-6 45-7 11-23 9-35 9-19-1-35-16-40-34-2-8-4-14-1-19 6-10 20-12 31-13l23-1z' fill='#333')
            path(d='M244 864a4 2 0 004 2 4 2 0 004-2 4 2 0 00-4-1 4 2 0 00-4 1' fill='#b3b3b3')
            path(d='M101 861l-19 66h17l18-65-16-1zM89 860h-4l-3 1-18 59 6 5z' fill='#fff')

    .page__half.page__half--back
      .book__insert
  - let p = 0
  - while (p < PAGES)
    .page.book__page(style=`--page-index: ${p + 2};`)
      .page__half.page__half--front
        +sketch
        .page__number= p * 2 + 1
      .page__half.page__half--back
        +sketch
        .page__number= p * 2 + 2
    - p++
  .page.book__page.book__cover.book__cover--back(style=`--page-index: ${PAGES + 2};`)
    .page__half.page__half--front
    .page__half.page__half--back
      span.code.
        set(FOLD,{transformOrigin:"50% 100%",scaleY:0}),set(CLIPS,{transformOrigin:"50% 0"}),set(".cannon__shirt",{opacity:0}),set(".cannon",{y:28}),set(".text--ordered .char",{y:"100%"});const SPEED=.15,FOLD_TL=()=>new timeline().to(LEFT_ARM,{duration:SPEED,rotateY:-180,transformOrigin:`${100*(22/65.3)}% 50%`},0).to(RIGHT_ARM,{duration:SPEED,rotateY:-180,transformOrigin:`${100*((65.3-22)/65.3)}% 50%`},SPEED).to(FOLD,{duration:SPEED/4,scaleY:1},2*SPEED).to(FOLD,{duration:SPEED,y:-47},2*SPEED+.01).to(CLIPS,{duration:SPEED,scaleY:.2},2*SPEED).to(".cannon",{duration:SPEED,y:0},2*SPEED),LOAD_TL=()=>new timeline().to(".button__shirt",{transformOrigin:"50% 13%",rotate:90,duration:.15}).to(".button__shirt",{duration:.15,y:60}).to(".t-shirt__cannon",{y:5,repeat:1,yoyo:!0,duration:.1}).to(".t-shirt__cannon",{y:50,duration:.5,delay:.1}),FIRE_TL=()=>new timeline().set(".t-shirt__cannon",{rotate:48,x:-85,scale:2.5}).set(".cannon__shirt",{opacity:1}).to(".t-shirt__cannon-content",{duration:1,y:-35}).to(".t-shirt__cannon-content",{duration:.25,y:-37.5}).to(".t-shirt__cannon-content",{duration:.015,y:-30.5}).to(".cannon__shirt",{onStart:()=>CLIP.play(),duration:.5,y:"-25vmax"},"<").to(".text--ordered .char",{duration:.15,stagger:.1,y:"0%"}).to("button",{duration:.15*7,"--hue":116,"--lightness":55},"<"),ORDER_TL=new timeline({paused:!0});ORDER_TL.set(".cannon__shirt",{opacity:0}),ORDER_TL.set("button",{"--hue":260,"--lightness":20}),ORDER_TL.to("button",{scale:300/BUTTON.offsetWidth,duration:SPEED}),ORDER_TL.to(".text--order .char",{stagger:.1,y:"100%",duration:.1}),ORDER_TL.to(SHIRT,{x:BUTTON.offsetWidth/2-33,duration:.2}),ORDER_TL.add(FOLD_TL()),ORDER_TL.add(LOAD_TL()),ORDER_TL.add(FIRE_TL()),BUTTON.addEventListener("click",()=>{1===ORDER_TL.progress()?(document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--hue",360*Math.random()),ORDER_TL.time(0),ORDER_TL.pause()):0===ORDER_TL.progress()&&ORDER_TL.play()});
    .book__insert
      img.gsap-logo(src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/logo-man.svg')
```

CSS

```
  box-sizing border-box

:root
  --page-count 20
  --page-scroll 25
  --underline hsla(0, 0%, 25%, 0.4)
  --spine hsl(0, 0%, 0%)
  --cover hsl(0, 0%, 10%)
  --bg hsl(0, 0%, 30%)
  --insert hsl(0, 0%, 85%)
  --page hsl(0, 0%, 90%)

body
  width 100vw
  height calc(((var(--page-count) + 2) * var(--page-scroll)) * 1vh)
  background var(--bg)
  overflow-x hidden

h1
  text-align center
  font-size 1rem
  margin 0
  padding 0

// Core page styling
.page
  height 100%
  width 100%
  position relative
  transform-style preserve-3d

  .page__number
    position absolute
    color hsl(0, 0%, 50%)
    bottom 1rem
    font-size 1vmin

  &__half--front .page__number
      right 1rem
  &__half--back .page__number
      left 1rem

  &__half
    display flex
    align-items center
    justify-content center
    height 100%
    position absolute
    top 0
    left 0
    width 100%
    transform rotateY(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg)) translate3d(0, 0, calc((0.5 * var(--coefficient)) * 1px))

    $clip = inset(0 0.5% 0 0.5%)
    -webkit-clip-path $clip
    clip-path $clip

    &--front
      --rotation 0
      --coefficient 0
      backface-visibility hidden
      border-radius 0 5% 5% 0

    &--back
      --rotation 180
      --coefficient 2
      border-radius 5% 0 0 5%

.book
  height 40vmin
  position fixed
  width 30vmin
  min-width 150px
  min-height 200px
  top 50%
  left 50%
  transform translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5)
  transform-style preserve-3d
  perspective 1200px

  &__insert
    content ''
    position absolute
    height 94%
    width 94%
    background var(--insert)
    top 50%
    right -1rem
    transform translate(0, -50%)
    border-radius 5% 0 0 5%

  &__spine
    height 100%
    left 0
    top 0
    position absolute
    background var(--spine)
    transform-origin 0 50%
    width 12px
    transform translate3d(0, 0, -13px) scaleX(1) rotateY(0deg)
    // z-index -13

  &__page
    position absolute
    left 2%
    top 50%
    // border 2px solid black
    border-radius 0 5% 5% 0
    transform translate(0, -50%)
    height 94%
    width 94%
    z-index calc(((var(--page-count) + 2) - var(--page-index)) * 2)
    transform-origin 0% 50%

  &__cover
    border-radius 0 5% 5% 0
    height 100%
    width 100%
    position absolute
    top 50%
    left 0
    background var(--cover)

    &--front
      transform-origin 0 50%

      .page__half--back
        border-right 1rem solid var(--spine)


    &--back
      transform-origin 0% 50%

      .page__half--front
        border-left 1rem solid var(--spine)

      .book__insert
        left 0
        border-radius 0 5% 5% 0

  &__page:not(.book__cover) .page__half
    background repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0 1rem, var(--underline) 1rem calc(1rem + 1px), transparent calc(1rem + 1px)) 0 1rem / 100% 100% no-repeat, var(--page)

.sticker
  height 15%
  position absolute
  bottom 5%
  right 5%
  transform rotate(-25deg)

.code
  line-height 1.2
  font-family monospace
  white-space pre-line
  // text-align justify
  max-width 100%
  max-height 100%
  font-weight bold
  color hsl(0, 0% 6%)
  text-shadow 2px 2px 0 hsl(0, 0, 11%)
  border-radius 5%
  display block
  overflow hidden

.gsap-logo
  position absolute
  top 50%
  left 50%
  transform translate(-50%, -50%)
  opacity 0
  height 50%

img
  width 90%
  height 90%
  object-fit center
  z-index 2
```

JS

```
  gsap,
  ScrollTrigger,
  gsap: { to, set },
} = window

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

to('.book', {
  scrollTrigger: {
    scrub: 1,
    start: () => 0,
    end: () => window.innerHeight * 0.25,
  },
  scale: 1,
})

to('.gsap-logo', {
  scrollTrigger: {
    scrub: true,
    start: () => 13.5 * (window.innerHeight * 0.25),
    end: () => 14 * (window.innerHeight * 0.25),
  },
  opacity: 1,
})

const PAGES = [...document.querySelectorAll('.book__page')]
PAGES.forEach((page, index) => {
  set(page, { z: index === 0 ? 13 : -index * 1 })
  if (index === 11) return false
  to(page, {
    rotateY: `-=${180 - index / 2}`,
    scrollTrigger: {
      scrub: 1,
      start: () => (index + 1) * (window.innerHeight * 0.25),
      end: () => (index + 2) * (window.innerHeight * 0.25),
    },
  })
  to(page, {
    z: index === 0 ? -13 : index,
    scrollTrigger: {
      scrub: 1,
      start: () => (index + 1) * (window.innerHeight * 0.25),
      end: () => (index + 1.5) * (window.innerHeight * 0.25),
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: Is this the link? But it just has like only one page of the book - https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Book-sketch.svg

Comment: 1. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Book-sketch.svg
2. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Cubes-sketch.svg
3. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Elon-sketch.svg
4. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Gun-sketch.svg
5. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Kitkat-sketch.svg

Comment: 6. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Launch-sketch.svg
7. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Pino-sketch.svg
8. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Pokedex-sketch.svg
9. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Record-sketch.svg
10. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/Tcannon-sketch.svg